# How to pass the *Customizer to a Spring Cloud Stream's binder context

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I noticed several customizers in the [KafkaBinderConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/9b8ebe235eddd3a2400146b1118b978e4ab685d7/binders/kafka-binder/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/config/KafkaBinderConfiguration.java#L109-L116), which we can pass to customize the binder. But in the case of multiple binders, the customizer beans won't be picked up. It may relate to this line in `DefaultBinderFactory`:

```
boolean useApplicationContextAsParent = binderProperties.isEmpty()
                && this.context != null;
```

How can these customizers be picked up in a binder context if this binder context's `useApplicationContextAsParent` equals to false?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binder-customizer

Use a `BinderCustomizer`.

> When an application has multiple binders in it and wants to customize the binders, then that can be achieved by providing a `BinderCustomizer` implementation. In the case of applications with a single binder, this special customizer is not necessary since the binder context can access the customization beans directly. However, this is not the case in a multi-binder scenario, since various binders live in different application contexts. ...