# How to pass BinderCustomizer to Spring cloud stream's BinderConfig?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to use the `BinderCustomizer` as suggested on [spring cloud stream documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#retry-and-dlq-processing).
I have multiple binders, both of which are `KafkaMessageChannelBinder`.

My code for BinderCustomizer :

```
  public BinderCustomizer binderCustomizer() {
    return (binder, binderName) -> {
      if (binder instanceof KafkaMessageChannelBinder) {
        ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binder).setRebalanceListener();
      }
    };
  }
```

But failing with a compatibility error.

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.Binder<capture<?>,org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ConsumerProperties,org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ProducerProperties>' to 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder'
```

I am using spring-cloud-stream:3.2.1.

Is there any alternate way to pass the "BinderCustomizer". Please advise

Comment: Referred other stack-overflow page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463344/how-to-pass-the-customizer-to-a-spring-cloud-streams-binder-context/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is unable to cast the `Binder<? ,? ?>` to `KafkaMessageChannelBinder`. We need to fix it. In the meantime, can you try the following workaround? Basically, we need to cast `Binder` to `AbstractBinder` first, then to `KafkaMessageChannelBinder.` I created an issue to fix this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2863

```
public BinderCustomizer binderCustomizer() {
    return (binder, binderName) -> {
      AbstractBinder aBinder = (AbstractBinder)binder;
      if (aBinder instanceof KafkaMessageChannelBinder) {
        ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binder).setRebalanceListener();
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: The fix is now in the `main`: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/b09892904864f1fe120a7d33ab3deb3a4d581063